# Proving isomorphism in lattices

Tags: proof-verification, order-theory, lattice-orders

The question is as follows:

Let f be a monomorphism from a lattice $L$ to a lattice $M$.Show that $L$ is isomorphic to a sublattice of $M$.

My attempt:

Since $f$ is a monomorphism from a lattice $L$ to a lattice $M$ therefore it will be a lattice homomorphism which is injective.
Since, $f$ is injective therefore every element of $L$ will be mapped into a unique element in $f(L)$ and hence $M$,and also every element of $f(L)$ will have a unique preimage.

Thus $f:L\to f(L)$ is bijective and hence a lattice homomorphism.
Further $f(L)$ is a sublattice of $M$ and hence $L$ is isomorphic to a sublattice of $M$.

Am I correct ?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score -1):

One thing that can be done is
First show that f(L) is sublattice of M 
After that 
Show that L is isomorphic to f(L) which is nothing but the sublattice of M

Comment: Not a comlete answer